# In Django how to return an existing model instance when saving to database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model, tdd

How do I return an instance before saving it to database?

Below it is something similar to what I am trying to accomplish:

```
class Personne(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Origem")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        found = None
        try:
            found = Personne.objects.get(nom=self.nom)
            super(Personne, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        except AudioFile.DoesNotExist:
            return found


def test_personne_is_the_same(self):
    p1 = Personne.objects.create(nom="Malcom X")
    p2 = Personne.objects.create(nom="Malcom X")
    self.assertEqual(p1, p2)
```

Assertion is giving:
p1 != None

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to accomplish but Django model gives a function called `get_or_create` which returns object and a flag which says created or not. i.e (obj, True or False). Also you may get error in save as your `found` will not be defined when `try` fails AFAIK.

Comment: Before saving that instance to the database I want to see if it already exists another with the same "nom" attribute. If it exists I want the create function to return not the new instance saved but the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why your `save()` method won't work as written. (For one, the return value of `save()` isn't used, so `return found` has no effect.)

But there's no reason to try and reinvent this yourself: get rid of your custom `save()` and just use `get_or_create()`:

```
def test_personne_is_the_same(self):
    p1, _ = Personne.objects.get_or_create(nom="Malcom X")
    p2, _ = Personne.objects.get_or_create(nom="Malcom X")
    self.assertEqual(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Django model gives a function called `get_or_create` which returns object and a flag which says created or not. i.e (obj, True or False).
So what you can do in `save` is.

```
found, created =  AudioFile.objects.get_or_create(nom=self.nom)
if created:
    super(Personne, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
return found
```

If this doenot work you can do

```
try:
    found = AudioFile.objects.get(nom=self.nom)
except AudioFile.DoesNotExist:
    found = AudioFile(nom=self.nom)
    found.save()
super(Personne, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
return found
```

Also shouldnot your `Personne` inherit `models.Model` ?

UPDATE:

Basically if there is no model called `AudioFile` and you are not checking relation in `Personne` then next answer is sensible choice to test.

Comment: I've edited my question with the good names, AudioFile should be Personne. And unfortunately that doesn't work either.